# Pricing of JFrog XRay as per the versions of JFrog Artifactory

Tags: jfrog-xray

I was working on Artifactory Pro version but thought of upgrading due to its limitations. I was confused which version of artifactory to use such that I get XRay license as well. I was more into buying the Artifactory Enterprise version but as I can see the pricing on this page, [xray-pricing](https://jfrog.com/pricing/xray-pricing/), I am a bit confused.

It shows **`JFrog XRay HA(Add-on option)`**. Correct me if I am wrong, does this mean that JFrog XRay will come with the enterprise edition but for the HA version of XRay, I will have to pay?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pricing question related to a third-party off-site vendor product. This is not JFrog Sales. Contact the vendor directly for questions relating to pricing or licensing of their product.

Comment: If this is still an issue, please drop me a note and I can route it to the correct people in our organization (I work for JFrog).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns pricing of third-party off-site vendor product.